# Value of count rows variable give me undefined although I assign it?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular-components

I work on angular 7 I face issue count rows variable give me undefined value

although returned data is 3

Expected result I need is Count rows must equal 3

```
public Countrows:Number;
ngOnInit(): void {
countitems()
console.log("final count rows is" + this.Countrows);

}
countitems()
 {
  this._inventory.GetcountItems().subscribe(
    data =>this.Countrows=data[0].countItems 

  )
 }
```

it give me final data  undefined although returned data value is 3

data returned  on count items function

```
[
    {
        "countItems": 3
    }
]
```

What I have tried:

```
console.log("final data" + data[0].countItems)
give me on console as 
final data 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is only set on the callback, not where you `console.log` it

```
 this._inventory.GetcountItems().subscribe(data => {
   console.log("final data" + data[0].countItems); // will work
   this.Countrows = data[0].countItems;
 });
```

---

#### Pseudo code

*component.html*

```html
<p>{{ countRowsDisplay }}</p>
```

*component.ts*

```ts
public countRows = 0;
public countRowsDisplay = '';
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getCountItems();
  // below line won't work. called before subscription
  // this.displayCountItems();
}

getCountItems() {
  this._inventory.GetcountItems().subscribe(data => {
    this.countRows = data[0].countItems;
    this.displayCountItems(); //works
  });
}

displayCountItems() {
  this.countRowsDisplay = `Rows returned: ${ this.countRows }`;
}
```

Comment: although i do it as posted above typically

Comment: should work inside the subscribe event if the `GetCountItems()` returns the data you mentioned. This will get you an pretty good idea about observables. https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

Comment: when make console .log for data[0].countItems it give me 3 but this.Coutrows give me undefined can you help me please

Comment: i get value is ok inside subscribe but outside subscript not working this._inventory.GetcountItems().subscribe(data => {
       
       this.Countrows = data[0].countItems;
       console.log("Inside final count rows is" + this.Countrows); // work give me 3

     });

     console.log("outside final count rows is" + this.Countrows);// not work and give me not defined

Comment: the value will be null till you subscribe, so if you use a function that uses the variable `this.CountRows`, **you must call it inside the subscribe callback after assigning the value** `this.Countrows = data[0].countItems;`